# Dynamics AX 2009 - Differentiating between Invoice and Credit Note

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

I was wondering whether or not it was possible to differentiate between an Invoice and Credit Note when using Dynamics AX 2009? As my understanding is that they get printed the same with the exception that a Credit Note contains negative values? The reason for asking is because I wish to get them out of the system in XML format using the AIF but transform each differently using different XSLT documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If `CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceAmount` (Sales ledger > Inquiries > Journals > Invoice > Invoice amount) is greater than or equal to 0 then it's an Invoice, if it's less than 0 then it's a Credit Note.

Comment: IS there anyway I can use this value in the Outbound Pipeline in AIF to use a different XSLT based on the invoice amount?

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer. I suggest to raise it as a new question in StackOverflow.

Comment: Did as you suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156783/aif-use-different-xslt-based-on-value - Feel free to have a go!